Washed out colour on UVProjected image (viewport and render)
a noobish question here - I'm learning to work with UVProject modifier, but the colours I'm getting are totally washed out, both in my viewport and in render.
What I already tried:

switching between cycles and eevee
turning on/off ambient occlusion
changing Colour Management settings in render tab.

Can you please suggest what am I doing wrong?
My nodes and image I'm getting:

Original image:

Other settings:


Do you have a completely black background? If you have any value in your World bg it will add that as ambient lighting to your scene. Also try messing with the Color space setting on your image texture node.

It was the background. Thank you!

Do I mark the question as answered? Can't find a way to do that.

If you are plugging the image into the Emission input of the Principled BSDF it will still be mixed with the white color of the Base Color, maybe instead use an Emission node?

Changing the background to black worked but I'll definitely try changing the nodes just to experiment a bit. Thanks

@Ithindir  I just added the solution as an answer, so accept that and it should close the question!

If you want to render an emissive material with 0 lighting contribution from the surroundings, make sure to set your background to fully Black.

vs.

